# Can Predict return non-numerical values?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I just started working with the Mathematica machine learning package.
When I use `Predict`, I can predict only numerical values like

```
Predict[{"ab"->1, "de"->2}]
```

Can I predict somehow non numerical values like

```
Predict[{"ab"->"c", "de"->"f"}]
```

or this

```
Predict[{"ab" -> {22, 33}, "de" -> {44, 55}}]
```

By default it does not work and gives an error message:

> Predict:Incompatible variable type (Numerical) and variable value({22,33})

Comment: The documentation does not explicitly say that `Predict` uses methods that only return numerical values, but the implicit message of all the examples is that it is so constrained.

Answer (score 1):

No, Predict is only for regression problems (so should be numerical). Based on your example it looks like you want Classify[] (or with ab -> c maybe SequencePredict[]).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Classify is not my case. I want to get unknown value, not something already existing. I will check SequencePredict.